# How to get user counts for both posts and comments, by certain tags?

Tags: sql-server, dataexplorer

With this dataexplorer query:

```
select b.DisplayName as owner, a.N from
(select OwnerUserId, count(*) as N from Posts where (Tags like '%perl6%' or Tags like '%rakudo%' or (Tags like '%parrot%' and Tags like '%perl%')) group by OwnerUserId) as a,
(select Id, DisplayName from Users) as b
where a.OwneruserId = b.Id order by N desc;
```

I can list all users that have posted some question with a certain tag.
However, **I'd like to also list the users that have answered or commented in posts with that tag.**

I guess it involves using the `Comment` table, however it's not clear to me how to merge the UserIds from both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [the SEDE schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede):

1. Get the questions by tags.
2. Better to use tests against the `Tags` table than using `LIKE` operations on the tags column.  The former can be 20 times faster.
3. Use the question list, from step 1 to get answers.
4. Use both the question list and the answer list to get comments.
5. Note that [SEDE provides wonderful magic columns](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) like `[User Link]`.

Putting it all together, here's one way:

```sql
WITH questsByTags AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
                q.Id
                , q.OwnerUserId
    FROM        Posts q
    INNER JOIN  PostTags pt     ON q.Id = pt.PostId
    INNER JOIN  Tags t          ON t.Id = pt.TagId
    WHERE       q.PostTypeId    = 1  -- questions
    AND (
            t.TagName   = 'perl6'
        OR  t.TagName   = 'rakudo'
        OR (
            t.TagName   = 'parrot'
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT      * FROM PostTags pt2
                INNER JOIN  Tags t2      ON  t2.Id = pt2.TagId
                WHERE q.Id = pt2.PostId  AND t2.TagName = 'perl'
    )   )   )
),
answersByTags AS (
    SELECT      a.Id
                , a.OwnerUserId
    FROM        Posts a
    INNER JOIN  questsByTags qbt  ON qbt.Id = a.ParentId
),
commntsByTags AS (
    SELECT      c.Id
                , c.UserId  AS [OwnerUserId]
    FROM        Comments c
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT              Id FROM questsByTags
        UNION ALL SELECT    Id FROM answersByTags
    ) AS allPosts
    ON allPosts.Id = c.PostId
),
allUsers AS (
    SELECT          OwnerUserId FROM questsByTags
    UNION SELECT    OwnerUserId FROM answersByTags
    UNION SELECT    OwnerUserId FROM commntsByTags
)
SELECT      au.OwnerUserId      AS [User Link]
            , (SELECT Count (qbt.Id) FROM questsByTags  qbt WHERE qbt.OwnerUserId = au.OwnerUserId)  AS [Num Qsts]
            , (SELECT Count (abt.Id) FROM answersByTags abt WHERE abt.OwnerUserId = au.OwnerUserId)  AS [Num Ans]
            , (SELECT Count (cbt.Id) FROM commntsByTags cbt WHERE cbt.OwnerUserId = au.OwnerUserId)  AS [Num Cmmnts]
FROM        allUsers au
WHERE       au.OwnerUserId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY    [Num Qsts] DESC, [Num Ans] DESC, [Num Cmmnts] DESC
```

You can **see it live, in action at [this SEDE link.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844618/number-of-questions-answers-and-comments-per-user-per-tag-set)**